# Struggling to get integrated soundcard to work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm having trouble locating the issue that is preventing my internal sound card from working on Focal - In the GUI I only get the dummy device.
Hardware probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=d01cc4f5cf

Running `alsa-info --stdout` gives me the below output:

```
alsactl: save_state:1595: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.eCla7TDuLz/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Thu Jul 30 19:57:32 UTC 2020


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Intel(R) Client Systems
Product Name:      NUC8i5BEK
Product Version:   J72742-308
Firmware Version:  BECFL357.86A.0077.2019.1127.1452
Board Vendor:      Intel Corporation
Board Name:        NUC8BEB


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT34BB:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:03/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:06/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.4.0-42-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.4.0-42-generic
Library version:    1.2.2
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa8a20000 irq 142


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9dc8] (rev 30) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2074]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_hda_intel: model=auto

!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : auto,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Realtek ALC233
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0235
Subsystem Id: 0x80862074
Revision Id: 0x100002
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Master Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC233 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x3c 0x3c]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x60]: 44100 48000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x57 0x57]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x60]: 44100 48000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x05 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC233 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x27 0x27]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 5
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010a: Mono Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x90a60150: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x5, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00010014: OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x40000000: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x16 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40050c: Mono Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0f
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x02a11040: [Jack] Mic at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0001373c: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400400: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40900001: [N/A] Aux at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x1
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=76
Node 0x21 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Master Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x02211010: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 6
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 7
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b 0x12
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x8086280b
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/hwC0D2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jul 30 12:46 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Jul 30 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 300 Jul 30 12:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Jul 30 12:46 pci-0000:00:1f.3 -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card PCH

Invalid card number.
Usage: amixer <options> [command]

!!Alsactl output
!!--------------
!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_tad
aesni_intel
af_alg
ahci
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
autofs4
bluetooth
bnep
bpfilter
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
e1000e
ecc
ecdh_generic
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_i801
i915
input_leds
intel_cstate
intel_pch_thermal
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_rapl_perf
intel_wmi_thunderbolt
ip6_tables
ip6table_filter
ip_tables
iptable_filter
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libahci
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
memstick
nls_iso8859_1
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_cannonlake
pinctrl_intel
ppdev
rfcomm
rtsx_pci
rtsx_pci_ms
rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sch_fq_codel
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soundcore
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
thunderbolt
uas
usb_storage
usbhid
video
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xt_multiport


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_pin_configs:
0x12 0x90a60150
0x14 0x40000000
0x17 0x411111f0
0x18 0x411111f0
0x19 0x02a11040
0x1a 0x411111f0
0x1b 0x411111f0
0x1d 0x40900001
0x1e 0x411111f0
0x21 0x02211010

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/hints:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_pin_configs:
0x05 0x18560010
0x06 0x18560010
0x07 0x18560010

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.178206] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.178206] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.178207] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    4.084021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    4.145596] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.150302] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.156923] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.160669] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
--
[    4.160672] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    4.214280] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC233: line_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:hp
[    4.214281] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.214282] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.214283] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.214283] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.214284] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    4.214285] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    4.488039] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8
[    4.488081] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
[    4.488116] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[    4.488146] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[    4.488180] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[    4.488211] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    4.488239] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    4.537048] audit: type=1400 audit(1596138400.814:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try kernel 5.7: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.11/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.11/amd64/)

I see new commits in the drivers listed for your problem device: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-9dc8-8086-2074

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I went as high as 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Your `alsa-info` output matches mine on a NUC8i7BEH, with the same Realtek ALC233 codec.

In your putput, ALSA has found the appropriate line out (front jack, on mine anyway):

```
 line_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:hp
```

At least on my machine, the GUI won't show an output in, say, GNOME sound settings until you plug something in. There's a very small risk the jack detect switch is broken in your unit, so perhaps wiggle the jack a bit and see if it shows up.

Assuming you've done that, use `sudo aplay -l` (sudo to avoid having it automagically routed via PulseAudio's view of the world) and see if you get output. If you do, there's something amiss between ALSA and whatever GUI you are using.

The output of `sudo amixer` would be handy, too, for the same reasons as above.

It would be worth checking `pavucontrol` as well to see if it can see the internal output. On my machine, it shows:

[pavucontrol screenshot showing Built-in Audio Stereo with "Headphones (plugged in) selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Ga1.png)

Comment: Thank you for this response! This is the output I'm getting from those commands. I have not yet got GNOME sound settings to display anything.other than "test device" or have the system make a sound.  I also have NUC specifically Intel NUC NUC8i5BEK, and i believe the headphone port does work. 
https://pastebin.com/BM59THfe